# Ruby: Remove everything after (and including) decimal

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got this string: `"37:48.1234567"` (there's a colon and there's a decimal in there)

I need to remove everything from the decimal and past it.

The number before the decimal could be any length (ie. `1:23:39.12357`).

Comment: You might want to spend an hour or two with some Ruby tutorials, and perhaps keep [apidock](apidock.com) bookmarked as a way to find out ways of doing things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
str.split(".")[0]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1; better than my `index` (and ironic, since I often suggest split).

Comment: Thanks, I always try and use split when it's a simple regular expression. Any idea if there is a performance hit in using split instead of regular expressions?

Comment: Not one that most people would care about.

Comment: "Any idea if there is a performance hit in using split instead of regular expressions?" Sounds like someone needs to spend a few minutes with `Benchmark`.

Comment: I'd probably write it as `str.split('.', 2).first`, but +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

I made a little benchmark with the solutions up to now.
I modified the solutions a bit.

One unclear problem: Whats the result for `1:23:39.123.57`? `1:23:39` or `1:23:39.123`?

I choosed `1:23:39`, only test regex has the other solution (see [Tims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8857283/676874))

The `split`variant has 2x2 variants: `[0]` or `.first` and split with a 2nd parameter `, 2`. The 2nd parameter of split limit the number of the splitted elements. We need only the first, so we may split in first and rest.

The fastes solution: `split('.', 2)`. If you use `first` or `[0]` makes no difference. I would prefer first.

The result ( `ruby 1.9.2p290` ):

```
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------------
regex           0.141000   0.000000   0.141000 (  0.140625)
regex2          0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
split[0]        0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
split[0],2      0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
split.first     0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
split.first,2   0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
---------------------------------------- total: 0.406000sec

                    user     system      total        real
regex           0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
regex2          0.109000   0.015000   0.124000 (  0.125000)
split[0]        0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
split[0],2      0.032000   0.000000   0.032000 (  0.031250)
split.first     0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
split.first,2   0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
```

The result ( `ruby 1.8.7p352` ):

```
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------------
regex           0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.060661)
regex2          0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.049141)
split[0]        0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.083703)
split[0],2      0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.072780)
split.first     0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.080419)
split.first,2   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.068370)
---------------------------------------- total: 0.410000sec

                    user     system      total        real
regex           0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.055427)
regex2          0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.048538)
split[0]        0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.084225)
split[0],2      0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.071673)
split.first     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.079865)
split.first,2   0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.068685)
```

The Benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'
TESTDATA = %w{
  37:48.1234567
  1:23:39.12357
  1:23:39.123.57
}
N = 10_000 #Number of Test loops

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('regex') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|str| str.gsub(/\.[^.]*\Z/, '') }} }
  b.report('regex2') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|str| str.gsub(/\..*\Z/, '') }} }
  b.report('split[0]') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{| str | str.split(".")[0] }} }
  b.report('split[0],2') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{| str | str.split(".",2)[0] }} }
  b.report('split.first') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{| str | str.split(".").first }} }
  b.report('split.first,2') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{| str | str.split(".",2).first }} }
  #~ b.report('') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{| str | }} }
  #~ b.report('') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|t| }} }
  #~ b.report('') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|t| }} }

} #Benchmark
```

Comment: what version do you use? I get pretty different results in 1.8.7.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32] - Can you modify my answer with your results? (Add it at the end with remark: Result of 1.8.7) Thank you

Comment: Wow! Look how much faster it is with 1.9.2—that's almost double the performance, damn.

Comment: @JessePollak I don't think you can compare the two benchmark - they are from different PC (and sorry, I don't have a installed version of ruby 1.8 on my PC). You can only compare inside each benchmark. In 1.8 the regex seems to be a bit faster, with 1.9 you should prefer split.

Comment: @knut yeah you're completely right, don't know what I was thinking. thanks for doing this!

Answer (score 3):

```
result = subject.gsub(/\.[^.]*\Z/, '')
```

does exactly this. It makes sure that if there is more than one decimal, only the last one will be affected.